# Handling events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I am using jQuery Steps and I am wanting to handle an event called: `onStepChanging`.

The default value is `function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) { return true; }`

I have tried the following, with no luck:

```
$("#wizard").onStepChanging(function (event, currentIndex, newIndex){
    Console.log("onStepChanging");
});
```

Can I please have some help to get this working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error/problem?

Comment: I don't know anything about jQuery steps, but I'm betting you'll need to do something like `$('#wizard').steps('onStepChanging', function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) { console.log('onStepChanging'); });`. The documentation doesn't specify the name of the actual event that's triggered on the element, so it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, it took a bit of trying, but this works:

```
$("#wizard").steps({
    headerTag: "h2",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    stepsOrientation: "vertical",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex){
        //alert("stepchanging event");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a lowercase 'c' for console.log().

Answer (score 0):

The "C" in "Console" should be lowercase. A good debug method for something like this would be to try a different output like `alert("This is working");` to tell if it is the event handler or the output that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("#wizard").on("stepchanging", function (event, currentIndex, newIndex){
    console.log("onStepChanging");
});
```

Just check the case of that first parameter. I'm not sure if the way I wrote will fit perfectly.

The $().on triggers a function then certain event is fired.

Also, the `console` is lowercase.